# Хранимые процедуры VS ORM

Tags: база-данных, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Видел в некоторых приложениях используют преимущественно хранимые процедуры, то есть приложение вообще не делает SELECT запросов в БД, а все получает через ХП в формате JSON.

Какие преимущества такого подхода? Всегда пользовался ORM ActiveRecord и был доволен.

Comment: Как мне кажется не нужно доставать из базы то что должно остаться там. Если нужно произвести какие то расчеты и сохранить опять в базу то зачем вытягивать их из базы а потом туда же вставлять. Пусть ХП произведет необходимые расчеты и обновит данные без выноса последних из базы. Если же необходимы какие то корректировки из вне тут хочешь не хочешь а вытаскивать придется.

Answer (score 0):

- #### Легко использовать повторно

  Хранимые процедуры достаточно определить один раз на уровне базы, после этого ими можно пользоваться откуда угодно: из голого SQL-клиента, из клиентов на других языках. Все клиенты будут гарантированно пользоваться одним и тем же кодом запросов, зная только имя.
- #### Определяются на "родном" для базы языке

  Рельсовый ActiveRecord предоставляет собственные мощности для составления запросов, но многие сложные или движко-специфичные запросы затолкать в них бывает довольно сложно. Разумеется, есть и другие ORM, которые умеют заметно больше, но хранимые процедуры изначально "родные" для базы, а код на каких бы там ни было ORM это производная от него.

---

Недостатков. на мой вкус, всё-таки больше:

- #### Сложнее менять

  Поскольку они меняются на уровне базы, все клиенты вынуждены использовать один и тот же код при обновлениях, даже старые. Поэтому менять интерфейс/сигнатуру у уже развернутых процедур — плохая идея. Чтобы внести изменения, нужна новая процедура, даже если самое удобное название для неё уже занято.
- #### Ещё один язык

  Сам продукт-то наверняка пишется **не** на процедурном SQL. И вуаля, внезапно разработчикам надо знать что-то ещё. Да и на мой личный субъективный взгляд все эти процедурные диалекты SQL синтаксически очень неудобны. Ruby лучше.
- #### Требуют портирования между разными СУБД

  Так что писать в таком стиле какие-то обобщённые плагины для Rails, требующие работы с базой, так себе идея: придётся реализовывать процедуры для каждого вида РСУБД, которую намерены поддерживать.
- #### Требуют именования и документирования, даже разовые

  Даже если какой-то запрос используется в проекте всего единожды, необходимо придумать ему название и подготовить внутреннюю документацию для него, как полагается для всего внутреннего API. Ну, по-хорошему.

  А если бы запрос был размещён "по месту использования", можно было б ограничиться документацией к тому модулю, что этот запрос использует, если вне этого модуля этот запрос вызывать нельзя (если не учитывать возможности копирования, конечно — но речь о том, где код размещается).

---

И нейтральщина:

- #### Не эффективнее по производительности

  ActiveRecord использует подготовленные инструкции (prepared statement), где может, поэтому даже огромные запросы отправляются в каждом соединении ровно один раз и далее адресуются по именам, похожим на хранимые процедуры образом. А вот будет ли использовать хранимая процедура подготовленные инструкции, будут ли кэшироваться планы запросов... зависит от многих вещей.